# Kelvin-Helmholtz instability for a continuous fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stability

I have a question about Kelvin-Helmholtz instability (KHI) for a continuous fluid.

I am new to hydrodynamics and I am currently working on a project about KHI.
For the past few days, I am looking for an intuitive explanation for the occurence of KHI in a continuous fluid. I found multiple intuitive explanations why KHI occurs when there is a velocity difference across the interface between two fluids.
So far, I haven't found anything about KHI in continuous fluids. This leads to the question,
what is the mechanism that makes KHI waves occur in a continuous fluid?

Comment: Are you talking about the stability of shear flow? If so, check out the [Rayleigh equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%27s_equation_(fluid_dynamics)) in the invsicid case and the [Orr-Sommerfield equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orr–Sommerfeld_equation) in the viscous case.